# What was Hermione's dad's job?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

I knew that he was a dentist in the movies, and I've read the books, but apparently, he either has a different job, or it's called different in the book... I want to know what this is, any answers die-hard HP fans?

Comment: What makes you think it's called different in the book?

Answer (score 8):

In the first book, Hermione replies that her parents are dentists when Ron suggests she ask them about Flamel:

> "Very safe, as they're both dentists"

In Goblet of Fire, Hermione mentions again that her parents are dentists:

> "Mum and Dad won't be too pleased. I've been trying to persuade them to let me shrink them for ages, but they wanted me to carry on with my braces. You know, they're dentists, they just don't think teeth and magic should —"

Comment: Do you have the page number?

Comment: She also mentions it in Philosopher's Stone: *"Very safe, as they're both dentists," said Hermione.*

Comment: @Trey page 263 [here](http://index-of.co.uk/Tutorials-2/Harry_Potter_-_Rowling,_J_K_-_Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire_-_Book_4.pdf), but I think that *the beginning of Chapter 23 - The Yule Ball* - is a more universal reference

Answer (score 2):

## Hermione's parents are both dentists.

Unlike you, I haven't seen the movies but can confirm this for the books.

From [the character's wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermione_Granger):

> Rowling adds that Hermione's parents, two Muggle dentists, are a bit bemused by their odd daughter but "very proud of her all the same."

From [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/hermione-granger):

> PARENTS 
>  Mr and Mrs Granger, both Muggles, both dentists

Answer (score 1):

## He’s a dentist in both the US and UK editions.

In both of the most common English-language versions of the Harry Potter series, both of Hermione’s parents are dentists - they never have a different job or a job called by a different name in either version. In the original British version, her parents are both dentists, which remains consistent throughout the books.

> “Hedwig had returned from Hermione’s house with a large box stuffed full of sugar-free snacks (Hermione’s parents were dentists).” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 3 (The Invitation) (British version)*</sup></sub>

This is stated early on in the series. In the first book, Hermione mentions her parents are both dentists.

> “And you could ask your parents if they know who Flamel is,” said Ron. “It’d be safe to ask them.”
>
> “Very safe, as they’re both dentists,” said Hermione. 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone, Chapter 12 (The Mirror of Erised) (American version)*</sup></sub>

In the US version as well, which makes certain changes to the words used and spelling to be better be understood by an American audience, Hermione’s parents are still dentists, and the term for their job is unchanged.

> “Hedwig had returned from Hermione’s house with a large box stuffed full of sugar-free snacks. (Hermione’s parents were dentists.)” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 3 (The Invitation) (American version)*</sup></sub>

The quotes in the British version that refer to her parents being dentists remain the same in the American versions.

> “And you could ask your parents if they know who Flamel is,” said Ron. “It’d be safe to ask them.”
>
> “Very safe, as they’re both dentists,” said Hermione.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone, Chapter 12 (The Mirror of Erised) (American version)*</sup></sub>

There are three references to Hermione’s parents being dentists in the original British text of the series.

> “Mum and Dad won’t be too pleased. I’ve been trying to persuade them to let me shrink them for ages, but they wanted me to carry on with my brace. You know, they’re dentists, they just don’t think teeth and magic should – look!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 23 (The Yule Ball)*</sup></sub>

All three quotes referring to Hermione’s parents being dentists remain exactly the same in the American version.

> “Mum and Dad won’t be too pleased. I’ve been trying to persuade them to let me shrink them for ages, but they wanted me to carry on with my braces. You know, they’re dentists, they just don’t think teeth and magic should — look!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 23 (The Yule Ball)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, both of Hermione’s parents are, and consistently have been, dentists throughout the Harry Potter series, in both common English versions of the books.